# How to put a shell parameter in a string inside a string?

Tags: bash, shell, parameters

There is a parameter $1. It's an email address. I want it to be part of the string within a string of this curl command:

```
curl 'xy.com' --data-binary '{"email":"variableValueHere!!!"}'
```

So a command including the parameter `$1` should result in this command...

```
curl 'xy.com' --data-binary '{"email":"xy@z.de"}'
```

if `$1` equals `xy@z.de`.

How can I put it in there?
What I tried so far:

```
curl 'xy.com' --data-binary '{"email":"$1"}'
curl 'xy.com' --data-binary '{"email":"`echo $1`"}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl 'xy.com' --data-binary '{"email":"'"$1"'"}'
```

It's the concatenation of

- `'{"email":"'`
- `"$1"`
- `'"}'`

and inserts your parameter as a quoted string.

Answer (score 2):

Better use a proper JSON parser like `jq`:

```sh
curl 'xy.com' --data-binary "$(
  jq \
    --arg email "$1" \
    --null-input \
    --compact-output \
    '.email = $email'
)"
```

- `"$(jq ...)"`: Captures the output of `jq` as a string.
- `jq`: Is a command-line JSON processor.

  - `--arg email "$1"`: Pass the shell's argument `$1`'s value as the `jq` variable `$email`.
  - `--null-input`: Tells `jq` there is no JSON input stream to parse.
  - `--compact-output`: Tells `jq` to compact its output by putting each JSON object on a single line.
  - `'.email = $email'`: This is the `jq` query to assign the value of the `$email` variable as the JSON string value of the `email` key from the root JSON object `.`.

This can also be written more compact:

```sh
curl 'xy.com' --data-binary "$(jq -cn --arg e "$1" '.email=$e')"
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you see when you try this:

```
curl 'xy.com' --data-binary '{"email":"`$1`"}'
```

Comment: The server receives the e-mail address '`$1`' (stackoverflow parses my text-input here)

Comment: ? Weird? Just for confirmation: in my answer, I've used backticks (not single quotes), did you use backticks too?

Comment: @Dominique : You have accidentally placed `$1` within backquotes!

Comment: That was not accidental: it's the whole idea! Backticks are not just used by StackOverflow for editing reasons, but also by UNIX for evaluation purposes.

Comment: Yes, but you certainly don't want to execute $1 as a command!!!

Comment: @user1934428 Oops, you're right. Your answer seems to be far better (and simplier).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
curl xy.com --data-binary "{email:$1}"
```

?

If you want the 3rd argument to be in JSON Format, write it as:

```
curl xy.com --data-binary  '{"email":"'"$1"'"}'
```

You can simplify this to

```
curl xy.com --data-binary  '{"email":"'$1'"}'
```

if you are sure that your email address (`$1`)  does not contain spaces or other troublesome characters.

If you really want to pass additional single quotes to curl (as you stated in your comment), just prepend and append to your argument a

```
"'"
```

Comment: The server won't be able to parse the JSON then because it's not valid JSON.

Comment: How is your question related to JSON? I don't see any mentioning of JSON in your text.  Please amend your posting and add a _json_ tag, if there is any json-issue involved.

Comment: It also would help if you could specify, which string exactly _curl_ is supposed to receive as 3rd parameter.

Comment: The string contains a JSON-object. The `{"email":"xy@z.de"}` is JSON. It's an object with an attribute "email" and the value "xy@z.de".

Comment: $1 is an email address like x@y.com and the curl command should look like this after the $1 is replaced with the email address: `curl 'xy.com' --data-binary '{"email":"x@y.com"}'`

Comment: So the server will only accept the request if the content after --data-binary is within `' and '` and the attribute and the email itself need to be within `" and "`.

Comment: Please update your question with this information. BTW: You say that the server (which server? You are just passing information to curl) requires **additional** single quotes around the third argument of the command. If this really is the case (I don't think so), you need to specify this in your question as well. Ideally you write for each of the three arguments exactly what strings you want to get passed to _curl_. The way it is right now, it is simply confusing.

Comment: It provides an answer to what ndsvw commented. As I said, he should put this information into the post, and not as a comment.

Comment: Just for clarification, the additional single quotes around the json string are not a requirement of json, they are a requirement for bash to successfully pass characters such as `{ `and `"` and `:` without interpreting them itself. The repetition of the single quotes in these answers is simply to help bash parse the command as intended.

Comment: If you don't have `jq` available: `curl xy.com --data-binary "$(printf '{"email":"%s"}' "$1")"` with same issue as your solution, because it does not warrant that "$1" will expand to a proper JSON string.